# What is the blast radius of the Archon's Blazing Pinions attack?

Tags: xcom-2

The Archon has an attack called "Blazing Pinions" that acts like an aerial strike against 4 random squad members. Each member that is targeted has a pillar of light on their tile location.

What is the blast radius of the attack around each pillar? I want to know how far away from each pillar I have to move my squad members so that they won't take any damage from the attack.

Comment: I had one of these shot at me the other day, and it seemed like about 2 squares from the pinion. Not 100% on that.

Comment: I confirmed that the blast radius is not 3, so it must be either 1 or 2 tiles.

Comment: Also remember that even after you kill the Archon, it doesn't cancel Blazing Pinions so watch out

Comment: It appears that pinions target squad members only when Archon has clear view of the targets. Sometimes Archon would initiate Blazing Pinions attack without a clear line of sight. In that case the strike points are essentially random, not tied to the current positions of your squad members.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some testing, I've confirmed that the blast radius of each pillar is exactly 2 tiles (not counting the center tile).

Visually, the blast radius looks like this:

[image]

The red and black tiles indicate where your units will definitely take damage. I'm not sure if any of the gray tiles on the diagonals are also in the blast radius though.

Comment: Does the damage taper down as we get further away from the center?

Comment: @AnT I don't know, but probably not.

Comment: Don't know if it was changed or maybe difficulty (I'm plaing WotC on L/I), but as for now, it's bigger than on the picture (the tiles like (x=1,y=2), (x=2,y=1), ..etc are also affected.

Comment: Im playing WotC on "normal" difficult, the second easiest level. And the blast radius was larger than this.

Answer (score -2):

The blast radius is at least every adjacent tile to the pinion tile. No idea if it's bigger.

Comment: It has to be bigger. I had a ranger who recently took a lot of damage from the attack that was at least 2 tiles away from a pillar.

Comment: -1, It's bigger.